# How test that ASP.NET MVC route redirects to other site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

Due to a prinitng error in some promotional material I have a site that is receiving a lot of requests which should be for one site arriving at another.
i.e.
The valid sites are `http://site1.com/abc` & `http://site2.com/def` but people are being told to go to `http://site1.com/def`.

I have control over site1 but not site2.

site1 contains logic for checking that the first part of the route is valid in an actionfilter, like this:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

    if ((!filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey("id")) 
     || (!manager.WhiteLabelExists(filterContext.ActionParameters["id"].ToString())))
    {
        if (filterContext.ActionParameters["id"].ToString().ToLowerInvariant().Equals("def"))
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("http://site2.com/def", true);
        }

        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "NoWhiteLabel" };
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to test the redirection to the other site though.
I already have tests for redirecting to "NoWhiteLabel" using the MvcContrib Test Helpers, but these aren't able to handle (as far as I can see) this situation.

How do I test the redirection to antoher site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend you using `RedirectResult` instead of calling `Response.Redirect`:

```
if (youWantToRedirect) 
{
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("http://site2.com/def")
}
else
{
    filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "NoWhiteLabel" };
}
```

Now if you know how to test `ViewResult` with MVCContrib `TestHelper` you will be able to test the `RedirectResult` the same way. The tricky part is mocking the `manager` to force it to satisfy the if condition.

---

UPDATE:

Here's how a sample test might look like:

```
    // arrange
    var mock = new MockRepository();
    var controller = mock.StrictMock<Controller>();
    new TestControllerBuilder().InitializeController(controller);
    var sut = new MyFilter();
    var aec = new ActionExecutingContext(
        controller.ControllerContext, 
        mock.StrictMock<ActionDescriptor>(), 
        new Dictionary<string, object>());

    // act
    sut.OnActionExecuting(aec);

    // assert
    aec.Result.ShouldBe<RedirectResult>("");
    var result = (RedirectResult)aec.Result;
    result.Url.ShouldEqual("http://site2.com/def", "");
```

---

Update (By Matt Lacey)
Here's how I actually got this working:

```
    // arrange
    var mock = new MockRepository();
    // Note that in the next line I create an actual instance of my real controller - couldn't get a mock to work correctly
    var controller = new HomeController(new Stubs.BlankContextInfoProvider(), new Stubs.BlankWhiteLabelManager());
    new TestControllerBuilder().InitializeController(controller);
    var sut = new UseBrandedViewModelAttribute(new Stubs.BlankWhiteLabelManager());

    var aec = new ActionExecutingContext(
        controller.ControllerContext,
        mock.StrictMock<ActionDescriptor>(),
        // being sure to specify the necessary action parameters
        new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "def" } });

    // act
    sut.OnActionExecuting(aec);

    // assert
    aec.Result.ShouldBe<RedirectResult>("");
    var result = (RedirectResult)aec.Result;
    result.Url.ShouldEqual("http://site2.com/def", "");
```

Comment: I get the following exception when trying to run this: "System.InvalidOperationException: Previous method 'ControllerContext.get_HttpContext();' requires a return value or an exception to throw."

Comment: @Darin - Thanks for the pointer. I eventually got this working (as shown above)